# Apple Music API, 'stations' Resource Type Playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am trying to play 'stations' resources from Apple Music Catalogue.

I retrieve the radio station via the Apple Music API i.e. [Search for Catalogue Resources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/search_for_catalog_resources)

which gives me a station response ([StationResponse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/stationresponse)):

```
{
  attributes =   {
    artwork =     {
      bgColor = ff9f0e;
      height = 1080;
      textColor1 = 0f0800;
      textColor2 = 190a00;
      textColor3 = 3f2603;
      textColor4 = 472802;
      url = "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Features111/v4/cd/ea/5a/cdea5a14-9789-26f5-8714-17b1db8f1021/source/{w}x{h}sr.jpeg";
      width = 4320;
    };
    editorialNotes =     {
      name = "Pure Country";
      short = "Today's biggest hits.";
    };
    isLive = 0;
    name = "Pure Country";
    playParams =     {
      format = tracks;
      id = "ra.985486583";
      kind = radioStation;
      stationHash = CgkIBBoF96n11QMQAg;
    };
    url = "https://music.apple.com/ca/station/pure-country/ra.985486583";
  };
  href = "/v1/catalog/ca/stations/ra.985486583";
  id = "ra.985486583";
  type = stations;
}
```

Normally, for other types of catalogue resources (playlists, albums, songs), I take the 'id' value and set it in the ```MPMusicPlayerController`'s playback queue and playback begins i.e.:

```
- (void)beginPlaybackForStoreID:(NSString *)storeID
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (@available(iOS 9.3, *)) {
            __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            // Store id for 'pure-country' radio station is: ra.985486583
            // https://music.apple.com/ca/station/pure-country/ra.985486583
            [strongSelf.musicPlayerController setQueueWithStoreIDs:@[storeID]];
            [strongSelf.musicPlayerController play];
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            NSLog(@"Not able to setQueueWithStoreIDs on this version of iOS");
        }
    });

}
```

'musicPlayerController' is an instance of the system music player [MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624179-systemmusicplayer?language=objc)

I receive this error only when the 'id' belongs to a radio station.

```
2020-05-20 10:37:42.681961-0700 ---[61653:10276450] [RemoteControl] userIdentityForMediaRemoteOptions -❗️No user identity data. Using active account.
2020-05-20 10:37:42.774906-0700 ---[61653:10276375] Audio session options array to bitmask: 1
2020-05-20 10:37:43.359056-0700 ---[61653:10276523] [SDKPlayback] 
-[MPMusicPlayerController prepareToPlayWithCompletionHandler:] completed id=systemMusicPlayer error: 
Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 122" 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 122, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x281170150 {Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 122 (MRMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus = 2)" 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 122 (MRMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus = 2), 
MPCPlayerErrorKeyMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus=2}}}
```

Is there a different mechanism for playing stations? For instance, maybe using AVPlayer to stream the station?

I've noticed that the 'playParams' in a station response contains two properties that other resources types do not contain: 'format' and 'stationHash'.

I can't seem to find anything in Apple's documentation regarding streaming radio stations.

Comment: I've gotten a response from Apple: 

"It is a limitation as it's not currently supported unfortunately. Team is aware of this, but I don't have an ETA to share as to when this will be functioning."